# Why is it correct to say "might have seen + definite time in the past"?

Tags: present-perfect

I have seen multiple examples of people saying things like,

"You might have seen yesterday that..."

Whereas saying "I have seen yesterday..." because we cannot use a definite time in the past with with present perfect...

Is 'might have + past participle' just an exception to the rule? Is it not considered present perfect?

Here are some examples of people saying that,

https://youglish.com/pronounce/might%20have%20seen%20yesterday/english?

There are 13 examples on this link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Only (tensed) "have" + pp. is "present perfect", with the special meaning of present relevance, and the restrictions on expressions of time.

When it follows a modal, or is infinitive (eg *might have seen*, *to have seen*) it is simply a sort of "past", not a "perfect", and doesn't have those restrictions.